# C++ Unable to Find Window

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm am able to FindWindow in game Plants vs. Zombies but no luck in Resident Evil. Can someone help me I'm relative new to this.

This is the code simple but no luck :(

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#define F6_Key 0x75

using namespace std ;



int main()
{
    cout << "Open Game .." << endl ;
    system("Pause") ;

    LPCWSTR game = L"Resident Evil 0 / biohazard 0 HD REMASTER";

    HWND hwnd = FindWindowW(0, L"Resident Evil / biohazard HD REMASTER");

    if (hwnd == 0)
    {
        cout << "Not Found." << endl ;
        system("Pause") ;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Success finding game." << endl;
    }

    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: Why are you storing a string literal in a variable, just to write it out again somewhere else?

Comment: I took the sample from a Website  but if I remove the L it will mark as error on the parameter

Comment: I would enumerate the windows. Perhaps the title does not exactly match. Here is an example: https://gist.github.com/LeZuse/6994454

Comment: Rather than enumerate windows, it's probably easier to just get a window spying tool like WinSpy++ if the window's title bar isn't good enough.

Comment: I don't mean removing the `L`, but you are defining a variable `game`, and then later (when calling `FindWindowW`), you just write out **again** what you stored in the variable `game`, just use `game` (and they're different BTW)

Comment: Dont flame me guys. Those are 2 attempts. With both games. I'm experimenting, normally was using the game variable with WCHAR[] = L. I fixed it using WinSpy++. Sorry if I didnt explain well :(

Comment: You really need to read a book on C (or more), and then move on to C++. Windows programming would be next. Right now it looks like you learned programming by watching youtube videos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is that `FindWindowW` is failing because there is no top-level window with that name. You seem to be confused between

```
L"Resident Evil 0 / biohazard 0 HD REMASTER"
```

and

```
L"Resident Evil / biohazard HD REMASTER"
```

which are similar but not the same.

Double check the name of the window that you are looking for, and make sure that you have spelled it exactly correct. A tool like Spy++ is useful in such scenarios.

Comment: Oh sorry those are 2 attempts. With both game. I'm experimenting normally was using the game variable with WCHAR[] = L. Will try with WinSpy to see if I find something